# Easiest way to build a text/keyword search over a set of 100k+ documents (max 500 chars in size)

Tags: database, full-text-search, keyword-search

What is the easiest (read least time consuming) way to implement text/keyword search over a list of a few hundred thousand short text descriptions (of about 500 characters each)?

Peformance requirements: the database is updated once a day so updating can take as long as necessary, reads need to be fast to provide a good user experience for searching.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's full text search indexing feature allows you to implement a prototype easily

The documentation is here:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/